# Как реализовать авторизацию в node.js?

Tags: node.js, javascript

На данный момент сделал так:
Отправляю GET запросом логин/пароль.

```
var data = {
        'username': username,
        'password': password
        };

        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: 'login',
          data: data,
          success: console.log('response sucsess')
    });
```

На сервере принимаю и сверяю с базой:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {

    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : 'localhost',
        user     : 'user',
        password : 'password',
        database : 'database'
    });

    connection.connect();

    var username = req.query.username,
    password = req.query.password
    connection.query('SELECT password FROM `users` WHERE login = "' + username +'"',            function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        else if (rows.length > 0 && password == rows[0].password) {
            console.log('Hello');
        } else {
            console.log('Go away!');
        }
    });

    connection.end();
    res.end();
});
```

Но, походу, это все очень неправильно и небезопасно. Как сделать безопасную авторизацию с сессиями? Какой их общий принцип роботы? Можно ли какой-либо готовый пример вида: отправил данные -> получил сессию и дальше проверяешь что-то вроде `if (user.registered){ ... }`?

Comment: @Veneomin, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: отправка GET-запросом чувствительных данных не самый лучший вариант (особенно, что касается логинов и паролей). Рекомендую использовать POST.

Answer (score 1):

В целом обычная схема.

Но лучше отправлять запрос через *POST*

```
$.post('/', data, callback);
```

В дальнейшем доступ к переменным будет не *req.query*, а *req.body*

p.s. Не забудь включить *app.use(express.urlencoded());*

Так же нужно добавить для параметров *connection.escape*

```
var username = connection.escape(req.query.username),
    password = connection.escape(req.query.password);
```

И по-хорошему отправлять *res.send()* для вывода результата на стороне клиента

```
if(rows.length > 0 && password == rows[0].password) {
    console.log('Hello');
    res.send(true);
} else {
    console.log('Go away!');
    res.send({
        error: "Ошибка авторизации"
    });
}
```